# Extract sub-string after match in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have string like **Order@Confirm@@@@2791** i wanted to fetch 2791 after @@@@ delimiter. I tried below one not getting exact sub-string what i am expecting to return.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Order @ Confirm @@@@2791','[^@@@@]+',1,2) regexp_substr
FROM dual;
```

I would like to return 2791 from above query.

Comment: Is the substring `@@@@` guaranteed to appear in your string? If not, what is the desired handling (result) when this substring is not present?

Comment: Yes, @@@@ is guaranteed for all. If not i would expect null.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Order @ Confirm @@@@2791','@@@@(.*)$',1,1, null, 1) regexp_substr
FROM dual;
```

If you want to restrict the match to digits:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Order @ Confirm @@@@2791','@@@@(\d+)$',1,1, null, 1) regexp_substr
FROM dual;
```

regexp_replace works too:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Order @ Confirm @@@@2791','.*?@@@@(\d+)$', '\1') regexp_replace
FROM dual;
```

Note with regexp_substr() if a match is not found NULL is returned and with regexp_replace() if a match is not found the original string is returned.

Comment: This solution worked. Got to know more usage of **REGEX_SUBSTR** function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

```
SELECT substr('Order @ Confirm @@@@2791', 
              instr('Order @ Confirm @@@@2791', '@@@@') + 4) as your_substr
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks this solution worked too, in terms of performance wise SUBSTR over takes REGEX_SUBSTR function call?

Comment: @PBD - "standard" string functions (SUBSTR, INSTR, REPLACE) are much faster (sometimes by an order of magnitude or more) than regular expression analogs. Regular expressions are a perfect tool when the matching rules are very complicated. In your case they are as simple as they can be; no need for regular expressions.